# Is there a faster way to remove duplicates among N containers?

Tags: java, algorithm

Suppose we have three arrays of fruits. Each array has different items, but some items are repeated in more than one array. I want to remove the duplicates so that the array only contains unique items.

Before:

```
arrayA = {"lychee", "orange", "grape", "watermelon"};
arrayB = {"banana", "grape", "pear", "apple"};
arrayC = {"pear", "orange", "strawberry", "apple"};
```

After:

```
arrayA = {"lychee", "watermelon"}
arrayB = {"banana"}
arrayC = {"strawberry"}
```

I have written the following Java code, which works, but I wonder if there is a faster algorithm.

---

Edit: I simplified the Java code and add doc. I wonder how to make the algorithm more efficient and lower the time complexity.

---

This is the pseudocode version:

```
    declare method [@name=removeDuplicates] [@params={@name=NItems, @type=String-Matrix/Set-List}]:
        declare a variable [@name=MapList, @type=List[item:HashMap[key:String, value:Number]]] assign List.@new
        iterate NItems with @[index, element]:
            declare a variable [@name=nmap, @type=HashMap[key:String, value:Number]] assign HashMap.@new
            for each @[item] in @element, put [key:@item, value:0] to @[name=nmap]
            reference @[name=MapList][@index] to @[name=nmap]
        declare a variable [@name=result] with the same type of @NItems
        iterate NItems with @[index, element]:
            iterate MapList with @[mapIndex, mapElement] where @index != @mapIndex:
                iterate @element with @[item]:
                    if @mapElement[@mapIndex] contains the [key:@item]:
                        set the corresponding map @MapList[@index] update [key:@item, value:@old+1]
            set @result[@index] values: items from @MapList[@index] where it's value == 0
        return @result
```

This is the java code version:

```java
    /**
     * Remove duplicate items among N container
     * @param arrays list of item container, each container contains no duplicates,
     *               and the container is unordered internally, which can be considered as a Set
     * @return N containers after remove duplicates
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static String[][] removeDuplicates(String[]... arrays) {
        Map<String, Integer>[] maps = new Map[arrays.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            maps[i] = new HashMap<>();
            for (String itm : arrays[i]) {
                maps[i].put(itm, 0);
            }
        }
        String[][] result = new String[arrays.length][];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maps.length; j++) {
                if (j == i)
                    continue;
                for (String s : arrays[i]) {
                    if (maps[j].containsKey(s))
                        maps[i].compute(s, (_, v) -> v + 1);
                }
            }
            int finalI = i;
            result[i] = Arrays.stream(arrays[i])
                    .filter(itm -> maps[finalI].get(itm) < 1)
                    .toArray(String[]::new);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You can surely do better than this. Even without knowing Java, I can see an unusual approach that looks pretty inefficient. If you want to determine what values appear in multiple arrays, simply use a `HashMap<String, int>` to count occurrances. Walk through your arrays and increment the count for each string. This does assume that a value won't appear multiple times in a _single_ array. Then, do your stream with the filter that selects only those strings with a count equal to 1.

Comment: you shouldnt need to `Arrays.stream(arrays[i]).toList()`. Streaming the list then addAll is like iterating the same array twice? You should just `sets[i].addAll(List.of(arrays[i]));`

Comment: If the code works, the question might be better suited for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would use sets and take advantage of the methods provided.

Comment: What if the _same array_ has duplicate values? Like : `arrayA = {"lychee", "orange", "grape", "watermelon", "cherry", "cherry"};`

Comment: I second @paddy's suggestion. The hashmap constructed from `arr = {arrayA, arrayB, arrayC}` would be `{"lychee"=1, "orange"=2, "grape"=2, "watermelon"=1, "banana"=1, "pear"=2, "apple"=2, "strawberry"=1}`. Then, in pseudo code, `arr.each { |a| a.reject! { |fruit| h[fruit] > 1 } } #=> { { "lychee", "watermelon" }, {"banana"}, {"strawberry" } }`, where `reject!` changes each array (`arrayA`, `arrayB` and `arrayC`) in place. Then `arrayA #=> { "lychee", "watermelon" }`, `arrayB #=> {"banana"}` and `arrayC #=> {"strawberry"}`.  My Java formatting may be off as I'm not familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is fairly simple:

```java
final var map = Stream.of(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(), 
            Collectors.counting()));

map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1);

arrayA.removeIf(map::containsKey);
arrayB.removeIf(map::containsKey);
arrayC.removeIf(map::containsKey);
```

---

Here is the breakdown:

Assume mutable `Set`s with the fruits:

```java
final var arrayA = new HashSet<>(Set.of("lychee", "orange", "grape", "watermelon"));
final var arrayB = new HashSet<>(Set.of("banana", "grape", "pear", "apple"));
final var arrayC = new HashSet<>(Set.of("pear", "orange", "strawberry", "apple"));
```

Now you want to collect a `Map` with the information about how many times each fruit (key) is present in all the `Set`s defined above.

```java
final var map = Stream.of(arrayA, arrayB, arrayC)
                .flatMap(Set::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Function.identity(), 
                        Collectors.counting()));
```

> ```
> {banana=1, orange=2, apple=2, lychee=1, pear=2, strawberry=1, watermelon=1, grape=2}
> ```

Now you need to retain only these occurring more than once. There is a one-liner for it:

```java
map.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() == 1);
```

> ```
> {orange=2, apple=2, pear=2, grape=2}
> ```

Finally, remove from each `Set` all the fruits that are present in this `Map`:

```java
arrayA.removeIf(map::containsKey);
arrayB.removeIf(map::containsKey);
arrayC.removeIf(map::containsKey);
```

> ```
> [lychee, watermelon]
> [banana]
> [strawberry]
> ```

Comment: Is it correct to say that the algorithm scans N containers, identifies items that occur more than once, and then deletes those items from all the containers? Thanks for your correct and great answer, but I still have some doubts: Does this answer is the optimal solution? Is there any way to reduce the time complexity of the algorithm even more?

Comment: Thank you :) The solution is IMO optimal as it is easy to read, understand, and maintain. That's the goal #1 of coding. Anything else like premature optimization rather causes harm. Regarding the time complexity, unless you face millions of entries, I would personally not bother and prefer the traits listed in the first sentence. Or do you have a specific business requirement, face billions of data, doing HackerRank or are you only curious? I am sure the solution can be further optimized compromising readability, but I'd leave it for further answerers (it's always better to have more choices).

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way.

```
public static String[][] removeDuplicates(Set<String>... sets) {
  Set<String> seen = new HashSet<>();
  List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for (Set<String> set : sets) {
    set.removeAll(seen);
    seen.addAll(set);
    result.add(set.toArray(new String[set.size()]));
  }

  return result.toArray(new String[result.size()][]);
}
```

The above avoids multiple iterations and nested loops, by using the set method removeAll for elements belonging to a set of items already seen.

To trigger the call to the function using your original input arrays, you do do.

```
String[][] noDups = removeDuplicates(
    new HashSet<>(List.of(arrayA)),
    new HashSet<>(List.of(arrayB)),
    new HashSet<>(List.of(arrayC)));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is incorrect. The problem with your answer is that the items at the end of the array will be filtered more than the items at the beginning of the array. Using my input, your answer's output is: `[orange, lychee, grape, watermelon], [banana, apple, pear], [strawberry]`, that's not expected

Comment: @EmiyaElien Looks like I misunderstood your question. You don't want to see the duplicates in any of the result lists, right? So, orange, grape, pear, and apple should not appear in any of the lists, correct? In this case, I have solved a different problem, which is to eliminate duplicates, while preserving all the inputs in some list. This problem by its very nature has multiple solutions, as one has to decide what list keeps an item and the order or processing can affect the solution. I could adjust the code to solve you problem, but I think you've got some really good answers already.